# How to restrict rest api client in Node Js Express

Tags: node.js, express

are there any code/third party libraries to stop api testing using rest api clients for Express/node api testing after production ? or how to restrict rest api client or limit it to particular number  of  tester .

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**In a nutshell, you can't.** Any tool like postman or any script (such as node.js, PHP, Perl, etc...) can send whatever headers or other request parameters it wants so headers by themselves are useless for restricting access to only a web page in your domain.

That's just how the web works.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355333/8437740) awesome explanation on SO